# AngularJS callback function not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, callback, angularjs-factory

I am using WebAPI on the server side:

```
    public int Get(int productId)
    {
        //removed the actual logic to simplify the example
        return 101;
    }
```

The Angular:

```
$scope.showDetails = function (product) {
    $scope.selectedProduct = product;
    var queryArgs = { productId: product.id };
    $scope.averageQuantity = Quantity.query(queryArgs, function() {
        //callback function
        console.log($scope.averageQuantity); // this shows a promise instead of an actual object
        //and then open modal and pass the $scope as a parameter
    });
};

//the resource:
.factory('Quantity', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/quantity', {}, { 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } });
}])
```

Instead of the number 101 I see the promise: {"0":"1","1":"0","2":"1"}

How can I implement the callback in order to see the object and not the promise?

Comment: It appears that you've committed a similar error as the OP in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749148/cannot-read-response-from-angularjs-resource-delete (See: RobM's answer) Instead of trying to pass a callback as a parameter, you need to use `then`, such as `$scope.averageQuantity = Quantity.query(queryArgs).then(function(results){ /* console.log(results.data */ })`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Marc. I think then() method is a jQuery specific method and I am not using jQuery on this project (I was asked not to). I looked at that link and I was indeed missing a parameter (for post data), which was right before the success function. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. It makes me think it might actually be a $resource misconfiguration rather than a callback issue? This is what I've tried: `$scope.averageQuantity = Quantity.query(queryArgs, {}, 
            function(returnValue, responseHeaders) {
                console.log(returnValue);
            });`

Comment: `then` isn't jQuery specific. Angular includes $q, patterned after Q for promises, which includes a `then` method. Still, I must admit that I was wrong in my initial judgement. The problem has nothing to do with callbacks or promises. My upcoming answer will show what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not your callback implementation. The problem is that you're using `$resource`, which is meant for use with RESTful API resources that return *JSON formatted strings*, with a service that returns plain-text with no structured formatting.

**Solution 1:**

If you're able to change the format of the data your WebAPI server returns, you can have it return a simple JSON object. It could be something like:

`{"value": "101"}`

Then, your `$resource` will be work more or less as is.

**Solution 2:**

If you can't or otherwise don't want to modify your WebAPI response, you can use `$http` instead of `$resource` in Angular:

`$http.get('example', {params: params});`

This will work to retrieve a plain-text response without munging the response data the way `$resource` does.

[Working Plunker demonstrating both methods](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2wPsSY3hzgvpCIoA3nq?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, Marc! I used something very similar by making use of $http, here's the code: `$scope.showDetails = function(product) {
            $scope.selectedProduct = product;
            $http.get('/api/quantity?productId=' + product.id).then(function (results) {
                $scope.averageQuantity = results.data;
            });
    };`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are including application/json headers and json data from webapi, seems like you aren't.